# Format body of email sent by Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen a few questions about this topic but none specific/similar to this scenario.

The body of an email is received via an input in an userform. I now want to format it as Calibri size 11. I've tried a few methods and although the code doesn't error out, when the email is populated, it is still Times New Roman 12.

The first body line calls the text box and is where I've attempted to add the formatting. The second line was necessary for maintaining line breaks.

Sorry for the basic question, I'm still learning!

```
        .To = UserName
        .cc = txtCC
        .BCC = txtBCC
        .Importance = Importance
        .Subject = txtSubject.Value
        .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>txtBody.Value</font></p>"
        .HTMLBody = Replace(UserForm1.txtBody.Text, vbCrLf, "<br>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I'm not sure if I can help but here some tipps:

Why do you write the html body and then just override it with the text from the userform.textbox?

Instead try something like:

```
.To = UserName
.cc = txtCC
.BCC = txtBCC
.Importance = Importance
.Subject = txtSubject.Value
AdaptedText = Replace(UserForm1.txtBody.Text, vbCrLf, "<br>")
.HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>" & AdaptedText & "</font></p>"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and helped me understand where I went wrong!

Answer (score 1):

@Kathara's solution worked fine for me, but also remove that `</font>` tag.

Comment: always happy to help :) I'm not too familiar with html, so this was all I could do :)